# Android app with multiple MasterFlow/Activities layouts example?

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments, android-activity, master-detail

I know how to change the activity, without use of Master Detail Flow Template but I need to make an app with multiple Master Detail Flow layouts.

I think that a single Master Detail Flow Layout is already a little bit complex and confuse alone, but it must be more confuse when there's necessity of multiple app screens.

Someone knows a good tutorial on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need, did you ever get any response or found the solution? I have a List that is a Menu, with around 10 entries and each entry requires a different activity/screenlayout.

EDIT:
I have found this very good tutorial: http://www.michenux.net/android-fragment-swapping-325.html. After making the needed adjustments for my app, change until 10 different layouts in the detailFragment, based on item selected in masterFragment, it works perfect for me.

Comment: No. And I have not tried yet. But maybe I have some clues that might help.

You can have multiple Master Detail Flow Layout in the same application. In Eclipse, you can add a new Master Detail Flow Layout via Ctrl + N-> Android-> Android Activity-> Next-> Master Detail Flow. After that you can change the activity as you wish, but not sure how to it.

Comment: However I am inclined to think that the better would be to create your own layout from scratch using the library AndroidAnnotations: http://androidannotations.org/

This will give you an important knowledge about activities and fragments and the use of that library will greatly facilitate the development and maintenance of your applications.